# What is an efficient way to use "apply" method on a subset of dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe to which i would like to apply "apply" method across rows, but i need to do it only on the subset of columns (say, 60%). I am wondering what is an efficient way to do it?

I know i can stash the rest of unneeded columns into the index using set_index and then reset it back, but i am curious if there is a more efficient way to do it.

I can certainly do:

```
df_new=df[[x1,x2,...xn]].apply(function, axis=0)
```

but the problem with this is that it `df_new` loses the rest of columns (and the index), so it is hard to restore it back to the expected output, which is the original frame with "apply" appplied only to certain number of selected columns.
Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: What is this method? you can [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) the df with a percentage and then mask the df and `apply` your function but ideally you should just call a vectorised function on that portion of the df

Comment: Please update your question with further details, raw input data, code and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the result to the same subset of df:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4))
print(df)
          0         1         2         3
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
1  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357
2 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
3  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
4  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096

df[[1, 2]] = df[[1, 2]].apply(lambda x: 100 + x)
print(df)

          0           1           2         3
0  1.764052  100.400157  100.978738  2.240893
1  1.867558   99.022722  100.950088 -0.151357
2 -0.103219  100.410599  100.144044  1.454274
3  0.761038  100.121675  100.443863  0.333674
4  1.494079   99.794842  100.313068 -0.854096
```

Make a copy if you want to preserve the original dataframe.

This might not work if you have mixed dtypes.